# What does an "A/an before the comparative/superlative adjectives" change in the sentence, semantincally?

Tags: grammaticality

What is the difference when you use a/an before comparative/superlative adjectives and when you do not use it? Does it depend on the context or is there a grammatical rule? which one is correct?

For example:

> 1) That usage of verb gives the sentence a more formal look.
>
> 2) That usage of verb gives the sentence more formal look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To figure out whether you need an article, look at the following noun:

- If you're talking about ***more hair***, you don't need an article because ***hair*** doesn't need one.
- If you're talking about ***a more formal look***, you do need an article because the noun ***look*** needs one.

Adjectives aren't relevant in this context.

Answer (score 2):

You must always use *a/an* there; in fact you're missing one earlier on in the sentence.  The correct way to write the sentence would be:

> That usage of ***a*** verb gives the sentence a better formal look.

Comment: +1 But: "Of the two sentences, #1 gives  *the* better formal look." :)

Comment: + another 1, but *a better formal look* sounds clunky to me anyway. I'd say *a **more** formal look* (or more likely, *appearance*). Arguably the original was intended to mean *both this usage and some alternative are equally "formal", but **this** one is actually **better** for some unspecified and unconnected reason*. But in that case I'd find some other way of putting it anyway.